# what can you say about the degree of $f:\mathbb{C}P^n \to \mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology-cohomology

Any thoughts on this problem:

If $M$ and $N$ are simply-connected, $n$-dimensional manifolds, then $H^n(M;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z} \cong H^n(N;\mathbb{Z})$. A map $f:M \to N$ induces a map $f^*:H^n(N;\mathbb{Z}) \to H^n(M;\mathbb{Z})$, which is to say: $f^*:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$. Any such map is given by multiplication by an integer $d$, and this integer is known as the degree of $f$, denoted by $deg(f)$. I have 2 questions:

(1) Let $f:\mathbb{C}P^2 \to \mathbb{C}P^2$. is it possible that $deg(f)=8$? is it possible that $deg(f)=9$? what can you say about the degree of $f$.

(2) what can you say about the degree of $f:\mathbb{C}P^n \to \mathbb{C}P^n$.

I know that we need to use the generators for each cohomology rings, but that is my issue I'm having trouble with this kind of questions. any help is appreciated. thanx in advance.

Comment: $f^*$ is a homomorphism of rings. What does it do to the generator of $H^2$?

Comment: have no idea!!!

Comment: for (1) I can set it up for $n=1$; $f:\mathbb{C}P^1 \to \mathbb{C}P^1$ whic means $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ which is a multiplication of 8, right

Comment: A restriction of $f^*$ sends $H^2(\Bbb{C}P^2)=\Bbb{Z}u$ to itself (as a homomorphism of groups). So what choices have we got for $f^*(u)$ (here $u$ stands for a generator of the second integral cohomology). What does that say about $f^*(u^n)$?

Comment: is it $u^n n^n$??

Comment: Depends on what $f^*(u)$ is. Anyway the point is that the structure of the cohomology ring (in the case projective space) means tha what happens at the level of the second cohomology affects what happens at the top cohomology.

Comment: I know that since each path component must be sent to path component, for $H^2 \cong \mathbb{Z}<x>$, we have $x \mapsto nx$ right?

Comment: Something like that. After we moved to the level of homomorphisms of cohomology rings we can more or less forget about the geometric interpretations. But you are using $n$ in two different roles, because part 2) of the question deals with $\Bbb{C}P^n$, so I would say $x\mapsto ax$ for some integer $a$.

Comment: yeah, so instead I'll use $x \mapsto kx$ implies that $x^n \mapsto k^n x^n$. am I correct? sorry but I have really hard time understanding the process. where $k$ is a constant.

Comment: So in the case of $\Bbb{C}P^2$ you see that at the level of top cohomology $x^2$ is multiplied by $k^2$. A rewriting of question 1 is thus: Is it possible that $k^2=8$? $k^2=9$?

Comment: is is related to perfect square? the answer is no for the first and yes for the 2nd!

Comment: Correct (though you do need a topological argument to show that all the squares occur). What about part 2?

Comment: we will generalize it to $ x^n \mapsto k^n x^n$

Comment: @user122350, **please** answer your old questions, as it seems you know answers to them.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, any map from $\mathbb{C}P^n$ to itself must have degree a perfect $n$th power.  But do all such degrees actually arise?  Yes.

Consider the map $f_k:\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ given by $f([z_0:...z_n]) = [z_0^k:z_1^k:...:z_n^k]$.

This is well defined:  $f([\lambda z_0:...:\lambda z_n]) = [\lambda^k z_0^k:...:\lambda^k z_n^k] = [z_0^k:...z_n^k]$.

I claim the map $f_k$ has degree $k^n$.  As mentioned in the comments, it is enough to show $f_k^\ast:H^2(\mathbb{C}P^n)\rightarrow H^2(\mathbb{C}P^n)$ is multiplication by $k$.  This is probably easier done in terms of homology.

Consider the natural inclusion $S^2\cong \mathbb{C}P^1\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^n$ given by mapping $[z_0:z_1]\in \mathbb{C}P^1$ to $[z_0:z_1:0...:0]\in\mathbb{C}P^n$.  It is well known that this inclusion induces an isomorphism on on $H_2$.  Further, the map $f_k$ preserves this $S^2$.

Thus, we get a commutative diagram \begin{array}
SS^2 & \stackrel{f_k}{\longrightarrow} & S^2 \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\mathbb{C}P^n & \stackrel{f_k}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{C}P^n
\end{array}

Since the maps from $S^2$ to $\mathbb{C}P^n$ are isomorphisms on $H_2$, we reduce the problem to computing $(f_k)_\ast:H_2(S^2)\rightarrow H_2(S^2)$.  But from the usual identification of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ with $S^2$, we see that $f_k$ is the map which preserves each line of lattitude, wrapping it around itself $k$ times.  Thus $(f_k)_\ast$ is multiplication by $k$.

Comment: Incidentally, if one tries to repeat the argument for $\mathbb{H}P^n$, one direction works great:  degrees must be perfect $n$th powers.  However, there are more obstructions (see, for example, Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, page 493).  Related, the map $f_k$ above is *not* well defined on $\mathbb{H}P^n$ due to lack of commutativity.

Comment: Can you explain why "inclusion induces an isomorphism on on $H_2$"?

Comment: @テレビスクリーン:  I think the easiest way to see this is to think in terms of the usual CW structure.  Then $S^2\cong \mathbb{C}P^1$ is the $3$-skeleton of $\mathbb{C}P^n$.